# F013, F104, F110 вместо картинок на сайте, после установки малоизвестной CMS на локальный сервер

Tags: изображения, сервер, cms, установка

уважаемые коллеги!

Скачал и установил на локальный сервер CMS. Все функции благополучно работают, но большинство картинок интерфейса не выводятся. Подумал, что дело в путях. Пример того, как разработчик организовал вывод картинок - ниже. Картинки, которые не подгружаются, хранятся, например, по таким путям: localhost/d/gallery/carousel, localhost/d/images/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Локальный сервер у меня OpenServer. Сколько не бился, сам не смог решить проблему. CMS малоизвестная, разработчик на вопросы не отвечает..

```
if   ($gtype==1) {  if ($dest=="") {
$scr.= "opener.document.form.foto1.value=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
opener.document.getElementById('smallimg').src='' + pt + image;
";} else {
$scr.="  opener.document.getElementById('el_".$dest."').value=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
";}}
if   ($gtype==2) { if ($minify_big==1) { $thumb=1; } $fbase=$fotobasebig; if ($dest=="") { $scr.="opener.document.form.foto2.value+=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'><br>\";
";} else {$scr.= "opener.document.getElementById('el_".$dest."').value=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
";} }
//new big foto proc
if   ($gtype==1000) { if ($minify_big==1) { $thumb=1; } if ($dest=="") { $scr.="opener.document.form.foto2.value+=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'><br>\";
";} else {$scr.="opener.document.getElementById('".$dest."').value='' + pt + image;
opener.document.getElementById('el_".$dest."').src='' + pt + image;
";} }
if   ($gtype==1002) { if ($minify_big==1) { $thumb=1; } if ($dest=="") { $scr.="opener.document.form.foto2.value+=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'><br>\";
";} else {$scr.="opener.document.getElementById('".$dest."').innerHTML='' + pt + image;
";} }
if   ($gtype==4) { $fbase="uploads"; if ($dest=="textar") {$scr.="opener.document.getElementById('textarea').value+=\"[img]\" + pt + image + \"[/img]\\n\";
";} else { $scr.="opener.document.getElementById('".$dest."').value+=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
"; }}
if   ($gtype==44) { if ($dest=="textar") {$scr.="opener.document.getElementById('textarea').value+=\"[img]\" + pt + image + \"[/img]\\n\";
";} else { $scr.="opener.document.getElementById('".$dest."').value+=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
"; }}
if   ($gtype==3) { $scr.="opener.document.getElementById('el_".$dest."').value=\"<img src='\" + pt + image + \"'>\";
opener.document.getElementById('img_".$dest."').src='' + pt + image;
  ";}
```

Comment: разработчику там давно уже руки сломали за такой, кхм, код, и скорее всего он больше не программирует

Comment: в браузере инспектор в инструментах откройте, посмотрите какие пути формируются для этих картинок. потом проверьте, что картинки на самом деле лежат на месте. или выясните, где именно они лежат.

Comment: Да, это-то понятно, просто суть в том, как бы картинки поправить..

Comment: и это вообще больше похоже на шрифты неподключенные, чем на картинки. Вкладку Сеть откройте, и проверьте, что там среди подключаемых файлов нет 404х ошибок. И консоль на наличие js ошибок

Comment: Если исследовать в инспекторе, то есть класс css и ссылка на какой-то элемент класса php, вот в таком виде: " ::before ..

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь! Я уже голову сломал)

Comment: В "Сети" статус либо "200", либо ничего, а в консоли три шрифтовые ошибки. Одна из них: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0

Comment: убедитесь, что указанный шрифт находится по данному пути. Добейтесь настройками апача, чтобы он не блокировался, или чего там с ним у вас происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз просто перенес папку с шрифтами в корень localhost.. Все заработало.. Сайт я в подпапку ставил, так как у меня несколько сайтов там..

Comment: в опенсервере домены настройте просто локальные, будут несколько сайтов каждый в своей папке.